# Shimano MegaRange what type?

Tags: shimano, derailleur

[image: Shimano]

Can anyone identify this Shimano derailleur?

Comment: The exact model doesn't matter if you're replacing it. You just need a shimano compatible 7-speed mtb derailleur.

Comment: RoboKaren: I see several rather cheap units on eBay, for instance a SHIMANO TOURNEY MEGARANGE RD-MR40 7–21 SPEED BIKE REAR DERAILLEUR. Would it be OK?

Comment: It's placed on the left side of the bike? Never seen such a thing... (stupid me, its upside-down=)

Answer (score 4):

That's Shimano's C050 rear derailleur. It is comparable to Atlus and Tourney in quality and I believe only came as a 7 speed, like yours.

I've attached the technical manual so you can see how to set it up properly. If you're looking to replace it, Shimano provided a lot of high end 7 speed rear mechs. For a mountain bike that would include things like exage, deore lx, and so on. The same time period for road and commuter bicycles would be exage, some rsx.

[image: C050]

Comment: My app is crashing when I try to insert images directly regardless of method. I submitted the bug report but if someone wanted to edit my post so the image would display instead of needing to follow a link it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One fair warning to add to the previous answer.  The "C" models from Shimano were Rapid Rise.  They don't make this system any more, but it means the cable pull is reversed and when you change this out for a non-rapid rise rear derailleur the shifters will read backwards.  This means when they say they are in 8th speed, they will actually be in 1st, and vice versa.  Non-rapid rise derailleurs are otherwise compatible with rapid rise shifters, and the shift points should all match up and work fine.  If you want the shifters to read correctly, you should change the shifters too.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the addition.